# The origin of the loss of the Fourth Wall?

Tags: analysis, first-appearance, origin, fourth-wall

"The Fourth Wall", for the uninitiated, is the wall that separates the movie from the audience, allowing the audience to be spectators to the events depicted.  Famously, the Fourth Wall was demolished like the end of a Pink Floyd concert in the 1986 film, [Ferris Beuller's Day Off](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091042/).

In the movie, the main character spent almost as much time talking directly to the audience as he did interacting with the film's other characters, filling us in on plot lines, thoughts and emotions so we got a deeper understanding of what was going on in the movie.

What I'm wondering is, when was this device first used in film?  While I'm not film student or expert, I can not think of a single movie prior to FBDO where the device is used.  I know John Cusack's character in High Fidelity did it often, and it was used throughout Fight Club, but it seems such an obvious method to really clue the audience in on what the character(s) is/are feeling.  Or is that just the reason not to; then you leave little to interpretation?

Comment: I think with such fourth wall breaks like in *Ferris Bueller's Day Off* there's always a thin line between being fascinating and feeling pretentious. Sometimes it just feels like cheap storytelling if done badly. There are much more interesting and subtle ways for inner monologues, like *Dune* or *The Beguiled* employed them. Just my two cents, interesting question though, but I have a strong doubt that *Ferris Bueller* really started this.

Comment: Other than that, while the last sentences of the question suggest a deeper and more interesting persepctive than just `first-appearance`, this deeper question isn't entirely clear from your text.

Comment: Now that I think about it, Bugs Bunny used this trope frequently too.  But those were shorts, not full-length feature films.

Comment: This question got me thinking about Rear Window. Hitchcock had Raymond Burr look straight at the camera in a way that didn't break the 4th wall. If you've seen the movie you remember the shot: it's Jimmy Stewart's POV, spying on murderer Raymond Burr standing in his apartment, and Raymond slowly turns to stare directly at him (and you). Chilling! But not REALLY breaking the 4th wall. (In "JFK", Kevin Costner also looked straight at the camera in the courtroom at the end, when he was talking about the records being sealed for 75 years.)

Comment: If this question is strictly about breaking the fourth wall, and not specifically about the forth wall and film... I'm reasonably sure that Shakespeare had actors speaking to the audience in many of his plays.

Comment: If we're not restricting this to film, then I'd argue that the fourth wall has been broken since the origin of theater in Greece (usually by the chorus, though arguably that's more akin to having a narrator). Also, what exactly do you mean by "demolished like the end of a Pink Floyd concert"? I mean, I guess you could be thinking of the destruction of The Wall at the end of "The Wall"...

Comment: At minimum you could date it to Denis Diderot, who originated the term "fourth wall" (mid 1700s).

Comment: It's not at all new or novel.  Many silent films did it.  So did Shakespeare.  So did others before that...

Comment: I was speaking specifically of film, as I am aware that Shakespeare (among other of his contemporaries) often broke the fourth wall.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/BreakingTheFourthWall/Film), the first use of this was in **1895**!:

> *[The breaking the fourth wall trope]* dates back to the Lumière brothers and the first films made for publicviewing in 1895—specifically, [The Photographical Congress Arrives in Lyon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Photographical_Congress_Arrives_in_Lyon), in which several of the photographers wave or doff their hats to the camera.

[image: Waving hat]

You can see more in [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzszLx-2Spc).

If you don't like that though, the [second oldest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metafilm) is [Hellzapoppin' (1941)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellzapoppin%27_%28film%29):

> The characters comment on other plots, they talk to the audience, they talk to the projectionist (and in fact, when the shot goes out of frame, they confront the projectionist, who it turned out was getting a little action in his booth), they deconstruct myths, they talk to still photographs (which come alive), they pause the phrase, mock the movie they're watching and the movie they're in (including muting the soundtrack and making jokes over it [MST3K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mst3k)-style), criticize the writing, talk about their roles, use double-exposures deliberately, control the direction, and have a running joke with overlaid wording that "Stinky Miller" needs to go to the lobby because his mother is looking for him, and the characters stop in the middle of a musical number to yell at Stinky, who eventually (in silhouette), gets up and leaves. Whew.
>
> **- TVTropes on Hellzapoppin'**

The projectionist fight scene described above can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ouLlA6IQZGI).

Comment: But was there actually any plot to that movie, or was it more like newsreel footage?

Comment: @JohnnyBones Wikipedia calls it a documentary film

Comment: Wow, that second example sounds like a complete fourthwallbreakgasm.

Comment: I am dedicating my life to tracking this one down.  :o)

Comment: @JohnnyBones It also includes one of the most famous (and awesome) swing-dancing scenes in music history (specifically the dancing scene in the kitchen). MrLore, I'm pretty sure documentaries don't *have* a fourth wall to break.

Comment: Watching it now.  Classic.  They utilize the concept of "Now Time" (a la Spaceballs) and re-wind the film at one point.  This, to use Napoleon's word, really is a fourthwallbreakgasm.  I'm somewhat surprised it's not more famous for being this groundbreaking.

Comment: I decided to replace the still image with an animated gif. Hope that's okay!

Comment: In one of the Marx Brothers' movies, maybe "Horse Feathers" (1932), Groucho looks at the camera and says he has to stay there but there's no reason the audience can't go out into the lobby. In another, maybe "The Big Store" (1941) he tells the audience that an actress's dress is bright red but they have to watch it in black and white because Technicolor is so expensive.